# Temporary disable new sign-ups from Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

How can I turn off new sign-ups from firebase console? Will it work if I disable the providers or re-enable it later? Actually I'm afraid disabling a provider will delete all the existing user accounts which uses that provider.

I just need to do it for few minutes to make a new deployment on our local server.

[I have checked this answer but doesn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084905/firebase-disable-new-user-signup)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling a provider will prevent anyone from signing up or signing in with that provider. It will not delete any existing user accounts however.

There is no way within the standard Firebase Authentication providers to disable sign-up, but still allow users to sign-in with a provider.

If you want to control who can use your application, you'll typically want to perform some other check, such as having a whitelist of approved users and checking against that.

Also see:

- [Is it possible to enable Firebase email authentication but disable sign in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715227/is-it-possible-to-enable-firebase-email-authentication-but-disable-sign-in)
- [Firebase Authentication with whitelisted email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552886/firebase-authentication-with-whitelisted-email-addresses)
- [Only allowing specific users to create account?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/68s0bs/only_allowing_specific_users_to_create_account/) (on Reddit)

Comment: Thank you for confirmation frank, No I don't want to allow any specific action like sing-in. It's just a temporary activity which we usually perform during non traffic hours it takes only few minutes. So I can disable all providers to temporary disable signups and sign-ins to my application.

Comment: Disabling the providers will prevent new sign-ups and sign-ins. But keep in mind that it doesn't invalidate existing ID tokens, so users that are already signed in can continue to use the app until their ID token expires.